# Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'TouchTracking.TouchTrackingPoint' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Point'

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

I want to Convert Xamarin.Forms point to pixels using skiapsharp. However error just say I cannot "Cannot implicitly convert type 'TouchTracking.TouchTrackingPoint' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Point'".I follow online document but still cant make it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch

```
    void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
    {
        Point pt = args.Location; //error occur here

        SKPoint point =
            new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                        (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));

        switch (args.Type)
        {
            case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                DisplayAlert("Alert", "X: " + args.Location.X + "Y: " + args.Location.Y, "OK");
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: There really ought to be a canonical answer for this on Stackoverflow, but I can't find it.  Just scads of similar questions, each dealing with a particular pair of different variable types.

Comment: Since it work fine in other project that I have downloaded, just curious whether I missed installing anything or not

Answer (score -1):

It is clear enough.

- args.Location is of type "TouchTracking.TouchTrackingPoint"
- pt is of type "Xamarin.Forms.Point"

You can't assign a variable of one type to a variable of another type.

If TouchTrackingPoint and Point are related (TouchTrackingPoint inherits from Point or both from a common base) then you could try this:

> Point pt = (Xamarin.Forms.Point)args.Location; //Tells the compiler explicitly that it is OK to convert one type to the other.  This will generate a compiler error if the types aren't compatible.

If the types aren't compatible, then you'll have to create a new point for pt, and pass the X and Y coordinates from args.Location to the constructor for Point.

As another alternative, you could just drop pt entirely.  All you need are the X and Y coordinates from args.Location - and you can access them just as easily as you can access the X and Y values for pt.

---

This is a common thing in dealing with different types of variables, and is **not** specific to Xamarin or SkiaSharp.

It's something you have to deal with in any language that enforces types.  Depending on the language, you will get a type error on compiling (as in this case) or a type error at run time.

It forces you to consider whether you can really just assign values from one type of variable to another type of variable.

Comment: Since it work fine in other project that I have downloaded, just curious whether I missed installing anything or not